# Access to a locally instantiated object

Tags: c++

I know this is a newbie question, but I'm having a bit of trouble with this.

Let's assume I'm trying to write something to a text field that I created.

I'll instantiate the textField class inside the entry point.
main.cpp:

```
#include "textField.h"  

void main()
{
  textField field;
  field.show();        
}
```

Now, in another source file, I'll try writing something to that textField.
hello.cpp

```
#include "textField.h"

void sayHello()
{
   field.write("Hello!");
}
```

Let's assume that **sayHello()** gets called somewhere else outside the main() function some time in the future. Let's also assume that many other files need access to that instance of TextField.

Of course this code won't work, so my question is: **Which method is recommended for being able to access that instance of the TextField class from another file?**

After some research I found some solutions, like making the textField a singleton, or some clever use of pointers, or even making the instance a global variable, but I'm not sure those are the optimal ways of doing this. I'm trying to keep global variables to a minimum.

I am able to find a solution by myself, but I'd like some input on the best coding practice for this kind of example.

Comment: you'll probably want to pass `field` in as a variable into your function, to use the original object you can use something like `void sayHello(textField& field){/*...*/}`

Comment: You can pass the object by reference as parameter.

Comment: @wizebin The point is that the sayHello function is not called inside main, but somewhere else in the code, so passing the reference for that textField from file to file would be a hassle. But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this textField is a real UI widget, I guess you can get it through window HWND or something in terms of what UI library you are using.

If this textField is just a sample name of a normal class, I think you can create a class named "GlobleVariable" or whatever the name is, and move instances you want to use globally into this class. This class can be singleton.

Comment: Alright, thanks! textField is just an example, it's not a real widget. I am trying to implement a QTextEdit widget using this style of code. I'll try using a singleton, although QWidgets don't have copy or assignment operator. In that case I could make the QTextEdit itself a singleton, or passing it as a pointer somehow.